# Vector: does the function vector ( const vector<T,Allocator>& x ); just take the address of where the array is stored?

Tags: c++, vector, allocator

If so can we assume there will be a null terminator at the end of the array?

Comment: Vector is not an array, and it is not null-terminated, which is a silly thing to do in a rich data-type.

Answer (score 2):

The `vector` copy constructor doesn't just copy the pointer to the vector's internal storage; it makes a *copy* of the other vector's contents. (If it just copied a pointer, then changes made to one vector would be reflected in the other vector, and as you know, that's not how the `vector` class behaves.)

Furthermore, there is no guarantee that there's anything special marking the end of the vector's internal storage. (And the internal storage isn't necessarily an array.) To detect the end of the vector, use the `size` function to help determine the highest allowed index for the vector, or compare an iterator against the one returned by `end`. Don't look for a sentinel value unless you put one there yourself, or your library documentation told you to expect one.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're talking about a constructor of `std::vector<T>`. That is the *copy constructor*, and it doesn't take an address of an array but a const reference to another vector. You, the provider of that other vector, do not need to add a terminating null.

```
std::vector<int> mine;
std::vector<int> theirs(mine);  // no particular change required for mine
```

Comment: "implementation-defined" is a technical term in the C++ standard, meaning that conforming implementations *must* document which choice they make. There's nothing in the standard to forbid an implementation from sticking a default-constructed element off the end of a vector (assuming `T` is even default constructible -- what does a "null terminator" even mean for user-defined types in general?), but there's certainly no requirement that the implementation warns you that it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, noted. What's the term for allowing an implementation to draw a flower past the end() iterator of each vector but not require them to mention it anywhere?

Comment: There's "unspecified", which means that the implementation has laid out a range of acceptable behavior, but the implementation isn't required to behave consistently or to document its behavior (so it could make a different choice each time, if it wanted). For example order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. For something like this, I think I'd normally just say that the the standard doesn't require the implementation *not* to draw a flower. I think it'd make sense to call such things unspecified, but that's implicitly, rather than any explicit statement of unspecified-ness.